# build artisan query from normal sql query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.6, tinker

I have a query in normal SQL below and I want to change it into artisan tinker query,

```
select count(P.id), DATEDIFF(P.tarehe_ya_kujifungua,P.tarehe_ya_kuzaliwa) as 
umri from postnatals P INNER JOIN register13s R ON P.namba_ya_kadi_RCH4 = 
R.Namba_ya_kadi WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tarehe_ya_hudhurio) = EXTRACT(MONTH 
FROM '2018-06-12') group by  P.id HAVING count(DISTINCT R.hudhurio) > 1 AND 
umri >= 7305;
```

I have a model `Postnatal.php` for `postnatals` table and also I have `Register13.php` for `register13s` table.

Comment: Check the description of the "tinker" tag, you might want to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how you can convert this query to Laravel Query builder.

```
DB::table('postnatals as P')
    ->innerJoin('register13s as R', 'P.namba_ya_kadi_RCH4','=', 'R.Namba_ya_kadi')
->whereRaw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tarehe_ya_hudhurio) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM '2018-06-12')')
->groupBy('P.id')
->having(DB::raw('count(DISTINCT R.hudhurio)'),'>',1)
->having('umri', '>', 7305)
->selectRaw('select count(P.id), DATEDIFF(P.tarehe_ya_kujifungua,P.tarehe_ya_kuzaliwa) as umri')
->get()
```

Hope this helps.